# Filtrado desde un tercer JOIN en Base de Datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando hacer un **JOIN** con las siguientes tres tablas.
Primero **entrada-salida con cliente** a través de un **LEFT JOIN**.
A su vez, igual con la tabla **pago**, con un **LEFT JOIN**.
Les muestro las tablas, su estructura y sus registros.
Todo esto con MYSQL

**CLIENTE**

```
CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
  `id_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_cliente` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_cliente` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `sexo_cliente` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email_cliente` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento_cliente` date NOT NULL,
  `telefono_cliente` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `estado_cliente` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `gimnasio_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url_imagen_cliente` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion_cliente` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `cliente` (`id_cliente`, `nombre_cliente`, `apellido_cliente`, `sexo_cliente`, `email_cliente`, `fecha_nacimiento_cliente`, `telefono_cliente`, `estado_cliente`, `gimnasio_cliente`, `url_imagen_cliente`, `fecha_creacion_cliente`) VALUES
    (20, 'Eliseo', 'VM', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2021-12-31', '9981505702', 1, 65, '127162643_10159108904568217_5842463868241141841_n.jpg', NULL),
    (21, 'Juana', 'Perez', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-14', '9981505702', 1, 64, '122678745_2762713470669451_2203428614279550983_o.jpg', NULL),
    (22, 'Pepe', 'Luna', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-10', '9981505702', 1, 72, 'Sin título111.png', NULL),
    (23, 'Alex', 'Mejilla', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-03', '9981505702', 1, 66, 'Sin título111.png', NULL),
    (26, 'Carlos', 'V', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-10', '9981505702', 1, 66, '122678745_2762713470669451_2203428614279550983_o.jpg', NULL),
    (27, 'Itzel', 'Portillo', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-14', '9981505702', 1, 66, 'Sin título111.png', NULL),
    (28, 'Lucia', 'Juarez', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '1994-07-19', '9981505702', 1, 68, '123140339_1519457401589137_5102889472902390156_n.jpg', NULL),
    (29, 'Omar', 'Chaparro', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-03', '9981505702', 1, 67, '20190609_112611.jpg', NULL),
    (30, 'Astrid', 'Lopez', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '1994-07-19', '9981505702', 1, 72, '122708132_1000704930432221_3500663975623121294_o.jpg', NULL),
    (31, 'Fanny', 'Galan', '', 'ultima@ultima.com', '2020-11-02', '9981505702', 1, 66, '123049280_184397109906000_7453044576460053003_o.jpg', NULL),
    (32, 'Federico', 'Quico', '', 'juan@juan.com', '2020-11-02', '9981-5057-02', 1, 66, '118988454_322259409191532_9047549356402945931_o.jpg', NULL),
    (33, 'Ariel', 'XX', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-03', '9981505702', 1, 67, '108031076_10208153574434112_6700955287415195789_o.jpg', NULL),
    (34, 'Lucia', 'Alamilla', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-02', '9981-5057-02', 1, 73, '108031076_10208153574434112_6700955287415195789_o.jpg', NULL),
    (35, 'Beatriz', 'Juarez', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2020-11-18', '9981-5057-02', 1, 64, '113242783_10208175112172542_1332820974758870271_o.jpg', NULL),
    (36, 'Ana', 'Dell', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '1994-07-19', '9981505702', 1, 71, '127162643_10159108904568217_5842463868241141841_n.jpg', NULL),
    (39, 'Logi Logi', 'Logi', '', 'logi@logi.com', '2021-01-20', '9981505050', 1, 76, 'aprender-ingles.jpg', NULL),
    (40, 'Fede', 'Perez', '', 'logi@logi.com', '2021-01-27', '9981505050', 1, 64, 'unnamed.jpg', NULL),
    (42, 'Microsoft', 'Corporation', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2021-02-24', '9981505050', 1, 76, 'platzi.jpg', NULL),
    (44, 'Alma', 'China', '', 'logi@logi.com', '2021-01-20', '9981505050', 1, 76, 'eb7710e28b66bc1bfa26e60c0426cf0e.jpg', NULL),
    (45, 'Propiedad', 'propiedad', '', 'logi@logi.com', '2021-01-20', '9981505050', 1, 65, 'unnamed.jpg', NULL),
    (46, 'Guadalupe', 'Tijuana', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2021-01-20', '9981505050', 1, 65, 'brackets-linguales-preguntas-frecuentes.jpg', NULL),
    (47, 'Luz', 'Nieto', '', 'eliseo-01@gmail.com', '2021-01-20', '9981505050', 1, 65, 'maxresdefault.jpg', NULL),
    (48, 'Nvidia', 'Nvidia', '', 'nvidia@nvidia.com', '2021-02-24', '9981505050', 1, 64, 'platzi.jpg', NULL),
    (49, 'Luis', 'Paca', '', '', '2021-03-24', '', 1, 64, 'pantalla-muy-larga-gaming-1024x576.jpg', NULL),
    (50, 'Pepe', 'Juarez', '', 'juarez@alave.com.mx', '2020-09-09', '9981505702', 1, 76, '', NULL),
    (51, 'Pepita', 'Nana', '', '', '2020-05-20', '9981505702', 1, 79, '', NULL),
    (52, 'Pepe', 'Mujica', '', 'paragua@paraguay.com', '2021-04-24', '9981505702', 1, 64, '1366_200350.jpg', NULL),
    (53, 'Clark', 'Kent', '', 'superman@superman.com', '2021-04-12', '9981505702', 1, 64, 'aprender-ingles.jpg', '2021-04-18'),
    (54, 'Venom', 'Simbionte', 'otro', 'simbionte@simbionte.com', '2021-06-10', '9981', 1, 64, '123049280_184397109906000_7453044576460053003_o.jpg', '2021-06-10'),
    (55, 'Peter', 'Parker', '', 'spiderman@spiderman.com', '2021-06-09', '9981', 1, 64, 'Captura de pantalla 2021-06-10 090108.png', '2021-06-10'),
    (56, 'Benito', 'Juarez', '', 'benito@benito.com', '2021-06-20', '9981', 1, 64, 'Captura de pantalla 2021-06-10 090108.png', '2021-06-10'),
    (57, 'Prueba', 'Prueba', '', 'prueba@prueba.com', '2021-06-25', '9981', 1, 64, '56848056_1210196885824870_5863649069448036352_n.jpg', '2021-06-11'),
    (58, 'Prueba2', 'Prueba2', '', 'prueba2@prueba2.com.mx', '2021-06-25', '9981', 1, 64, '56848056_1210196885824870_5863649069448036352_n.jpg', '2021-06-11'),
    (59, 'Prueba3', 'Prueba3', '', 'prueba3@prueba3.com.mx', '2021-06-17', '9981', 1, 64, '193064032_336448634560516_2941969823588855552_n.jpg', '2021-06-11'),
    (60, 'Prueba4', 'Prueba4', 'mujer', 'prueba4@prueba4.com.mx', '2021-06-17', '9981', 0, 64, 'Unidad de imagen T3.jpeg', '2021-06-11'),
    (61, 'Loki', 'Loki', 'otro', 'loki@loki.com.mx', '2021-06-25', '9981', 0, 64, 'Mensaje en la impresora.jpeg', '2021-06-11');
```

**ENTRADA-SALIDA**

```
CREATE TABLE `entrada_salida` (
  `id_entrada_salida` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cliente_entrada_salida` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_entrada_salida` date NOT NULL,
  `hora_entrada_salida` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `entrada_salida` (`id_entrada_salida`, `cliente_entrada_salida`, `fecha_entrada_salida`, `hora_entrada_salida`) VALUES
(43, 20, '2021-01-03', '17:03:27'),
(44, 20, '2021-01-03', '17:03:31'),
(46, 21, '2021-01-03', '17:03:40'),
(47, 21, '2021-01-03', '17:03:44'),
(48, 47, '2021-01-08', '20:37:32'),
(49, 47, '2021-01-08', '20:39:16'),
(52, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:39:45'),
(53, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:40:36'),
(54, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:40:37'),
(55, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:40:39'),
(56, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:42:10'),
(57, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:42:11'),
(58, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:42:12'),
(59, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:42:19'),
(60, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:42:20'),
(61, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:42:20'),
(62, 46, '2021-01-08', '20:42:30'),
(63, 20, '2021-01-08', '20:52:18'),
(64, 20, '2021-01-08', '20:53:11'),
(65, 20, '2021-01-08', '20:54:38'),
(66, 20, '2021-01-08', '20:58:21'),
(67, 20, '2021-01-08', '21:00:22'),
(68, 21, '2021-01-08', '21:01:19'),
(69, 21, '2021-01-08', '21:02:26'),
(70, 45, '2021-01-09', '14:41:09'),
(71, 22, '2021-01-12', '21:23:18'),
(72, 22, '2021-01-12', '21:23:57'),
(73, 48, '2021-01-12', '21:27:23'),
(74, 48, '2021-01-12', '21:27:26'),
(75, 48, '2021-01-13', '21:50:07'),
(76, 48, '2021-01-13', '21:50:24'),
(77, 34, '2021-01-16', '22:12:42'),
(78, 21, '2021-01-19', '23:08:00'),
(80, 21, '2021-02-04', '22:09:35'),
(81, 21, '2021-02-04', '22:11:15'),
(82, 21, '2021-03-09', '21:34:34'),
(83, 35, '2021-03-09', '22:00:08'),
(84, 21, '2021-03-14', '21:23:11'),
(85, 20, '2021-04-18', '12:57:35'),
(86, 53, '2021-06-09', '11:44:00'),
(87, 53, '2021-06-09', '11:45:49'),
(88, 53, '2021-06-14', '12:00:41'),
(89, 59, '2021-06-14', '12:07:03'),
(90, 58, '2021-06-14', '12:07:21'),
(91, 57, '2021-06-14', '12:08:01'),
(92, 56, '2021-06-14', '12:08:20'),
(93, 55, '2021-06-14', '12:09:59'),
(94, 54, '2021-06-14', '12:10:16'),
(95, 52, '2021-06-14', '12:10:38'),
(96, 49, '2021-06-14', '12:10:52'),
(97, 48, '2021-06-14', '12:11:07'),
(98, 40, '2021-06-14', '12:11:10'),
(99, 56, '2021-06-14', '12:11:30'),
(100, 21, '2021-06-14', '12:13:21'),
(101, 53, '2021-06-14', '12:13:34'),
(102, 53, '2021-06-15', '12:30:03');
```

**PAGO**

```
CREATE TABLE `pago` (
  `id_pago` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_cliente_pago` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cobertura_pago` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `pago` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion_pago` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `pago` (`id_pago`, `nombre_cliente_pago`, `cobertura_pago`, `pago`, `fecha_creacion_pago`) VALUES
(1, 20, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, 23, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(5, 26, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(6, 27, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(7, 28, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(8, 29, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(9, 30, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(10, 31, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(11, 32, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12, 33, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(13, 34, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(15, 36, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(16, 39, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(17, 53, '1971-01-27', '490.00', NULL),
(18, 42, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(19, 44, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(20, 45, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(21, 46, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(22, 47, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(23, 48, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(24, 49, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(25, 50, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(26, 51, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(27, 52, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(28, 53, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(29, 53, '2021-04-08', '300.00', '2021-04-02'),
(31, 30, '2021-04-02', '1234.00', '2021-04-24'),
(32, 30, '2021-04-03', '900.00', '2021-04-24'),
(33, 20, '2021-04-04', '900.50', '2021-04-25'),
(34, 54, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(35, 55, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(36, 56, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(37, 56, '2021-06-15', '300.00', '2021-06-11'),
(38, 57, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(39, 58, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(40, 59, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(41, 60, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(42, 56, '2021-06-16', '123.00', '2021-06-18');
```

Las tres tablas anteriormente mencionadas, hago la unión con la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT
    es.id_entrada_salida AS 'id_entrada_salida',
    es.fecha_entrada_salida AS 'f_entrada_salida',
    es.hora_entrada_salida AS 'h_entrada_salida',
    
    c.id_cliente AS 'id_cliente',
    c.nombre_cliente AS 'nombre_cliente',
    c.apellido_cliente AS 'apellido_cliente',
    c.gimnasio_cliente AS 'gimnasio_cliente',
    
    IFNULL(p.id_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'id_pago',
    IFNULL(p.nombre_cliente_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'id_cliente_en_el_pago',
    IFNULL(p.cobertura_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'cobertura_pago',
    IFNULL(p.pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'pago',
    IFNULL(p.fecha_creacion_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'fecha_pago'
    
FROM entrada_salida es
LEFT JOIN cliente c
ON es.cliente_entrada_salida = c.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN pago p
ON c.id_cliente = p.nombre_cliente_pago
WHERE c.gimnasio_cliente = 64

ORDER BY
    es.id_entrada_salida
DESC;
```

Lo cual me da como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

El detalle aquí, es que quiero mostrar **SOLO** el ultimo pago (de la tabla pago) del id_cliente y no me muestre los 3 pagos que tiene.
En este caso, muestra del id_entrada_salida (102) los tres pagos que tiene (1971-01-27, Sin datos, 2021-04-08).
Esto del id_entrada_salida para que no se repita (dependiendo del pago) utilicé un `GROUP BY es.id_entrada_salida` después del **WHERE** y **antes de ORDER BY**.
Ya que se repetía dependiendo del numero de pagos del cliente.
Lo cual me da como resultado lo siguiente.
[image: Sin id_entrada_salida repetidos]

Ahora no se me repiten los id_entrada_salida pero me muestra solo el primer pago del cliente (1971-01-27) y no el ultimo (2021-04-08) como se muestra en la imagen anterior.
Espero y haberme explicado bien, también poner toda la información posible y los detalles del problema en el cual quiero expresar bien este problema que tengo.
Hice un esfuerzo en solucionar el problema yo mismo, en investigar y leer, pero por el momento estoy bloqueado con este detalle de la consulta en la base de datos.
De antemano, muchas gracias por leer todo esto.

Comment: Puedes agregar la columna en el order by y agregar un limit, por ejemplo: `ORDER BY
   p.id_PAGO, es.id_entrada_salida
DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero al aplicar dicho cambio, solo me da el 100 de  id_entrada_salida.

Comment: Perdón, hay que cambiar el DESC por ASC

Comment: Solo me muestra el 46 de id_entrada_salida.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la salida esperada?

Comment: Ejemplo del ultimo id_entrada_salida 102 
2021-06-15 12:30:03 53 Clark Kent 64 17 53 2021-04-08 490.00 Sin datos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución está en agrupar por cllientes y no buscar todas las fechas sino solo la última max().

```
SELECT
es.id_entrada_salida AS 'id_entrada_salida',
es.fecha_entrada_salida AS 'f_entrada_salida',
es.hora_entrada_salida AS 'h_entrada_salida',

c.id_cliente AS 'id_cliente',
c.nombre_cliente AS 'nombre_cliente',
c.apellido_cliente AS 'apellido_cliente',
c.gimnasio_cliente AS 'gimnasio_cliente',

IFNULL(p.id_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'id_pago',
IFNULL(p.nombre_cliente_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'id_cliente_en_el_pago',
IFNULL(max(p.cobertura_pago), 'Sin datos') AS 'cobertura_pago',
IFNULL(p.pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'pago',
IFNULL(p.fecha_creacion_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'fecha_pago'

FROM entrada_salida es
JOIN cliente c ON es.cliente_entrada_salida = c.id_cliente
JOIN pago p ON c.id_cliente = p.nombre_cliente_pago
WHERE c.gimnasio_cliente = 64

GROUP BY nombre_cliente_pago
ASC;
```

Aquí muestra solo el último pago para los que tienen uno o más pagos.

Comment: El detalle aqui, es que ya no me aparecen todos los id_entrada_salida. Al agrupar por nombre_cliente_pago quito relevancia a la tabla entrada_salida y eso hace que no me muestre todo los id

Comment: He comprendido mal lo que necesitas, porque entiendo que si solo quieres el último pago no puedes tener todos los id_entrada_salida.  ¿?

Comment: En la primera imagen tengo 3 id_entrada_salida 102,102,102 que en la columna cobertura_pago hace referencia a la fecha del pago que son 3, 1971-01-27, Sin datos y 2021-04-08. Puedo agrupar los 2 id_entrada_salida como muestro en la imagen 2, pero al hacerlo, solo me muestra el ultimo cobertura_pago 1971-01-27 y no el ultimo, que es el 2021-04-08